# Unity & Daydream - Having Dialogs with other Characters

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, daydream

I am building a Daydream app via Unity, have a basic first person demo working but I have not developed on Unity before. Looking to add characters to the app and have dialogs with them. I am considering two ways:

1. When I go near to a character a dialog box would come up next to that character and say "Hello".
2. When I point to a character with the pointer it would say "start conversation"

After either case I would have multiple options to choose from eg. "Where is X" or "what is your name" etc then depending on my selection the character would respond with something else and so on. I couldn't see something that would solve this in standard assets. Are there any best practices, templates around this? If not any ideas / directions?

Unity 2017.3.1f1
GVR SDK: v1.130.1
Android Studio 3.0.1
Java jdk1.8.0_162.jdk
Pixel 2 phone
MacBook High Sierra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty easy just follow these steps;

Add a collider to the character,
and put a 3d text on where you want "Hello" to pop up and add a script like this;

```
public text HelloText = null;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
   HelloText.text.enabled = true;
}//Search more on google ; Unity 3d text.
```

Create a cube scale it as you desire and put a text in it like "Start Conversation". Add a collider to the cube and a script like this;

```
  void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //Create dialog boxes LIKE THIS.
    }
```

This is not the perfect way to do it. If you are new this might be the best option for you.

You can create a prefab which made of cube and a text. Then you can set their values thru script.

EDIT:

Create an empty game object and attach this script to it.
Then put 3rdPersonController gameobject to empty gameobject slot in empty game object's script

Example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AScriptName: MonoBehaviour {

 public GameObject PlayerController = null;
 TextMesh DialogBox = null;

void Start()
{

//Note: Attach your 3d text to your 3rdPersonController in the editor..

DialogBox = PlayerController.GetComponentInChildren(typeof(TextMesh)) as TextMesh;

DialogBox.text = "Start Conversation";

//or you can pass a string value;
//Example string text = "Start Conversation"; DialogBox.text = text;

}

}
```

Comment: 3d text; should it be a Game Object? Where do I add the script; to the Character (AIThirdPersonController) or the the new 3d text I created? Also have not used C# before,  should the complete script be like below?  using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;  
public class Conversation : MonoBehaviour {  
 // Use this for initialization  
 void Start () {  
 }  
 public text HelloText = null;  
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)  
 {  
  HelloText.text.enabled = true;  
 }  
}

Comment: Add OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) to your 3rdPersonController game object. Set 3d text as its child object on EDITOR. You can reach that child object like this ; TextMesh Text = 3rdPersonController.GetComponentInChildren(typeof(TextMesh)) as TextMesh; and change text value like this : Text.text = "Start Conversation"; I'm gonna edit my answer if you think thats an answer to your question set it as the answer.

Comment: thanks so much FaTaLL, I upvoted your response but apparently it doesnt reflect publicly as I do not have 15+ rep yet. One more question; looks like you removed OnCollisionEnter, how is this new script gonna be triggered only when my user approaches the character? PS: I set it up per my understanding: https://imgur.com/a/zTiOK

Comment: Add if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ThirdPersonPlayer"){//your code here} to oncollisionenter function. And set your 3rdpersonplayer's tag to ThirdPersonPlayer. Your good to go :). ps: you can set this as the answer of your question instead of upvoting.